# SequelizeDatabaseError Data truncated for column position at row 4

Tags: reactjs, express, sequelize.js, react-hooks

I am getting a `SequelizeDatabaseError Data truncated for column 'position' at row 4` while sending an update request as below: Any advise on how to fix the database error ?

Executing (default): UPDATE `user` SET `photo`=?,`name`=?,`email`=?,`phonenumber`=?,`position`=?,`password`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `email` = ?
SequelizeDatabaseError: Data truncated for column 'position' at row 4
    at Query.formatError (C:\Project\soccerpep\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:244:16)
    at Execute.handler [as onResult] (C:\Project\soccerpep\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:51:23)

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('user', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false

        },
        phonenumber: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),

        },
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        privilege: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM('PLAYER','ADMIN'),

        },
        photo: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),

        },
        position: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM('FORWARD','MID-FIELD','DEFENDER','GK'),

        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'user'
    });
};
```

`server.js`

```
const UserModel = userSchema(sequelize, DataTypes);

app.put('/service/profile', async (req, res, next) => {

  try {
    const userEmail = req.query.email;
    var selector = { 
      where: { email: userEmail }
    };
    const updatePlayer = await UserModel.update(req.body, selector);
    console.log("Server side update method log:" + updatePlayer);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is inside `req.body`?

Comment: Inside the req.body that position field is blank.

Comment: As I haven’t edited the position field. At the moment I have edited phonenumber and password field only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with ENUM, you can use that only with `Postgres` and not with `mysql` , ( **[Ref](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js~ENUM.html)** )

```
position: {
     type: DataTypes.ENUM('FORWARD','MID-FIELD','DEFENDER','GK'),
}
```

Change it to simple `string` type and check again,

```
position: {
     type: DataTypes.STRING(30)
}
```

> NOTE : You might need to create table again or update the field
>   manually after changing this in model else you will still get the
>   error

Comment: You are correct, I have changed to `DataTypes.STRING(100)` The error got disappeared.

Comment: One problem I see here is when the update req received, the other fields get wiped out, i mean the fields I haven't edited / updated

Comment: Your fields values might be empty,Remove all the empty fields while updating and just keep the fields with values,  or it will update it with blank

Comment: if you are familiar, could you please help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62525061/getting-an-association-error-user-is-not-associated-to-availability

Comment: i have change to string but i got same issue ` SequelizeDatabaseError: Data truncated for column 'segmen' at row 1` before my data is enum and work . but when i added new enum in database , the new enum doesnt work. did u know why ?

Answer (score 1):

Change datatype is not the solution. You have to check the data that you try to save. eg: if ENUM("0", "1") and you try to saved data 0 then it's showing that type of error. You have to save like that "0". Then it's not showing such type of error message again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ENUMs in mysql you should use it as so

```
position: {
    type: DataTypes.ENUM,
    values: ['player', 'admin],
    defaultValue: 'monthly' // A default value just incase you fail to provide one...
},
```

I do hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

i have a lot spending my day to tracing this error.

i have following all solution but doesnt work.

in my case and my bad is...
i forgot have **clone table/duplicate/history/trigger** that save old and new data.

make sure your history table have same data type.
i have table like these

```
form3
hs_form3 // its mean history with revision (number of revisi data) column and action column (create/update/delete/any)
```

just for description

```
CREATE TABLE hs_form3 LIKE form3;

ALTER TABLE hs_form3 MODIFY COLUMN id int(11) NOT NULL,
  DROP PRIMARY KEY, ENGINE = InnoDB, ADD action VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT 'insert' FIRST,
  ADD revision INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER action,
ADD dt_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER revision,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (revision),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
```

and i didnt run migration on server because a lot of change , i only run on localhost. in server i just put a new table by export import or added manual. before i got issue about migration on server and doesnt capture last change in sql table and dont have time to resolve.